# Robotframework: no keyword with name 'open browser' found

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework

I am trying to create a simple robot framework test, but when i run the following code, the test fails saying that there's no keyword for 'open browser'. It looks like the selenium library is not recognized, but I cannot understand why, as I have the required plugins installed (intellibot and robotframework support)

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Testing
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  AngularJSLibrary

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}  chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Testing
    begin web test

*** Keywords ***
Begin web test
    open browser  about:blank  ${BROWSER}
    maximize browser window
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Does it give you any warning about the library not being found when you execute the script in the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install robotframework-seleniumLibrary?? You can install by executing following command.
`pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary`
Official Page for reference: [official robot framework selenium library documentation](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary). Also you need to have chrome drivers installed [Download Chrome Driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Selenium library is missing from Machine. Following step can be done.

In the command prompt :

run command : pip list
It should contain following library : robotframework-seleniumlibrary

If not then install :  python -m pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary

Also then the IDE can be checked with the Interpreter or venv list of packages added in the project has the robotframework-seleniumlibrary added.